# Checksum did not match in 'npm i'

Tags: npm

when i use `npm i` to install node_moudles,but something was wrong.

It said:

```
PhantomJS not found on PATH
Download already available at C:\Users\hdu42\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip
Checksum did not match
```

[image: Sample Image]

But in fact, in this directory on my computer, this file exists.

I don't understand why should I redownload it.

Anybody know? thanks！！！

Answer (score 0):

Error is because of:

Phantomjs present in your `\Local\Temp` is not matching the checksum; defined in repository which is referring to PHANTOMJS_CDNURL-> environment variable.

Solution:

- Download phantomjs from https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip
- Extract the zip
- Add the path of bin `C:\Users\YourUser\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\phantomjs\bin;` in your environment path